# FlatFileFormat does not generate SSIS package Correctly

Tags: ssis, code-generation, biml

Biml (Or SSIS) doesn't seem to want to automatically identify the row Delimiter. Without a column with a manually set on the last column of the column list to the intended Row Delimiter SSIS does not set the delimiter correctly for the row.  I'm guessing that SSIS just implies the row delimiter even if it is set in the connection properties.  Any one know of a fix for this other than writing around the problem and setting the last column's delmiter to the intended row delimiter (See "T" Column below)?

I checked the properties of the output Connection and it properly states the "RowDelimiter" as the CRLF, but if you look at the

Here is the Biml file:

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
  <Connections>
    <OleDbConnection Name="Source" ConnectionString="Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=SSPI;">
    </OleDbConnection>
    <FlatFileConnection Name="Created" FilePath="D:\\created.dat" FileFormat="Changed">
      <Expressions>
        <Expression PropertyName="ConnectionString">@[$Package::FileDropRoot] + "\\"+REPLACE((DT_WSTR, 10)(DT_DBDATE)GETDATE(),"-","") + "." + "created.dat"</Expression>
      </Expressions>
    </FlatFileConnection>
  </Connections>
  <FileFormats>
    <FlatFileFormat Name="Changed" ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow="true" HeaderRowDelimiter="CRLF" RowDelimiter="CRLF">
      <Columns>
        <Column Name="col1" DataType="String" Delimiter="Comma" ColumnType="Delimited" />
        <Column Name="col2" DataType="String" Delimiter="Comma" ColumnType="Delimited"/>
        <!-- this must be here in order to terminate the row -->
        <Column Name="T" DataType="String" Delimiter="Comma" ColumnType="CRLF"/>
      </Columns>
    </FlatFileFormat>
  </FileFormats>
  <Packages>
    <Package Name="Test" ConstraintMode="Linear" ProtectionLevel="EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey">
      <Tasks>
        <Dataflow Name="Test">
          <Transformations>
            <OleDbSource Name="Select Stagement" ConnectionName="Source">
              <DirectInput>
                  Select * From Test
              </DirectInput>
            </OleDbSource>
           <FlatFileDestination Name="UpdateFile" ConnectionName="Created">
            </FlatFileDestination>
          </Transformations>
        </Dataflow>
      </Tasks>
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter Name="FileDropRoot" DataType="String">D:\FileDrop</Parameter>
      </Parameters>
    </Package>
  </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Here is the SSIS "Code" with the T Column above, please note that a Row Delimiter is specified (Line Breaks in export file):

```
<DTS:ConnectionManager DTS:CreationName="FLATFILE" DTS:DTSID="{9CDCB838-2A42-4CCA-A59C-DC60E9B3A967}" DTS:ObjectName="Created" DTS:refId="Package.ConnectionManagers[Created]">
  <DTS:ObjectData>
    <DTS:ConnectionManager DTS:CodePage="1252" DTS:ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow="True" DTS:ConnectionString="D:\\created.dat" DTS:Format="Delimited" DTS:HeaderRowDelimiter="_x000D__x000A_" DTS:LocaleID="1033" DTS:RowDelimiter="_x000D__x000A_" DTS:TextQualifier="_x003C_none_x003E_" DTS:Unicode="True">
      <DTS:FlatFileColumns>
        <DTS:FlatFileColumn DTS:ColumnDelimiter="_x002C_" DTS:ColumnType="Delimited" DTS:CreationName="" DTS:DataType="303" DTS:DTSID="{D64391D4-4551-44E9-8539-4C473EB700AA}" DTS:ObjectName="col1" DTS:TextQualified="True">
        </DTS:FlatFileColumn>
        <DTS:FlatFileColumn DTS:ColumnDelimiter="_x002C_" DTS:ColumnType="Delimited" DTS:CreationName="" DTS:DataType="303" DTS:DTSID="{974ED1AD-7D72-4A65-A877-BADEC09DAF20}" DTS:ObjectName="col2" DTS:TextQualified="True">
        </DTS:FlatFileColumn>
        <DTS:FlatFileColumn DTS:ColumnDelimiter="_x000D__x000A_" DTS:ColumnType="Delimited" DTS:CreationName="" DTS:DataType="303" DTS:DTSID="{4347C3C1-39BD-40B1-B38F-526730FE7BFB}" DTS:ObjectName="T" DTS:TextQualified="True">
        </DTS:FlatFileColumn>
      </DTS:FlatFileColumns>
    </DTS:ConnectionManager>
  </DTS:ObjectData>
  <DTS:PropertyExpression DTS:Name="ConnectionString">@[$Package::FileDropRoot] + "\\"+REPLACE((DT_WSTR, 10)(DT_DBDATE)GETDATE(),"-","") + "." + "created.dat"</DTS:PropertyExpression>
</DTS:ConnectionManager>
```

Here is the SSIS "Code" without the T Column above, please note that a Row Delimiter is specified (No line breaks in export file):

```
<DTS:ConnectionManager DTS:CreationName="FLATFILE" DTS:DTSID="{79E9C576-FD53-4D4F-A07C-AED8D4CE72E6}" DTS:ObjectName="Created" DTS:refId="Package.ConnectionManagers[Created]">
  <DTS:ObjectData>
    <DTS:ConnectionManager DTS:CodePage="1252" DTS:ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow="True" DTS:ConnectionString="D:\\created.dat" DTS:Format="Delimited" DTS:HeaderRowDelimiter="_x000D__x000A_" DTS:LocaleID="1033" DTS:RowDelimiter="_x000D__x000A_" DTS:TextQualifier="_x003C_none_x003E_" DTS:Unicode="True">
      <DTS:FlatFileColumns>
        <DTS:FlatFileColumn DTS:ColumnDelimiter="_x002C_" DTS:ColumnType="Delimited" DTS:CreationName="" DTS:DataType="303" DTS:DTSID="{BBCA22D2-5D3E-47AC-AA0A-413C0C1A5CB2}" DTS:ObjectName="col1" DTS:TextQualified="True">
        </DTS:FlatFileColumn>
        <DTS:FlatFileColumn DTS:ColumnDelimiter="_x002C_" DTS:ColumnType="Delimited" DTS:CreationName="" DTS:DataType="303" DTS:DTSID="{44E567E4-BE78-432C-A8AC-C388E8BCFADC}" DTS:ObjectName="col2" DTS:TextQualified="True">
        </DTS:FlatFileColumn>
      </DTS:FlatFileColumns>
    </DTS:ConnectionManager>
  </DTS:ObjectData>
  <DTS:PropertyExpression DTS:Name="ConnectionString">@[$Package::FileDropRoot] + "\\"+REPLACE((DT_WSTR, 10)(DT_DBDATE)GETDATE(),"-","") + "." + "created.dat"</DTS:PropertyExpression>
</DTS:ConnectionManager>
```

Here is the Script I used to Create the table on the database Connection

```
CREATE TABLE Test(col1 varchar(25),col2 varchar(25))

INSERT INTO Test 
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2' UNION all
SELECT '1','2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an incorrect assumption in that the last column's delimiter shouldn't be CRLF. You'll see in all the linked examples, while counter-intuitive, your flat file format file should use your row delimiter as the column delimiter for the final column. Every other column would use your "standard" column delimiter. And yes, it's repeated from the header declaration of what your row delimiter should be.

- http://bimlscript.com/Snippet/Details/18
- http://bimlscript.com/Snippet/Details/54

Some people juggle geese...